# Do I need to enable gzip compression in PHP if it’s already enabled in IIS?

Tags: php, http, iis, gzip, windows-server

I have PHP installed on a 2019 Windows Server with IIS. If I enable dynamic and static compression via IIS, do I also need to enable it in PHP as well? Or is everything from PHP (and anything else) automatically handled by IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this:

If IIS dynamic compression is enabled, it doesn't also need to be enabled in PHP.

Comment: Please mark the answer so that it can help others with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Static files like Html and Javascript should be compressed, whether in IIS or application itself. If the image, pdf or binary files are already in compressed formats, there is no need to compress them.

Enable compression in IIS, it will be classified as static or dynamic according to the file type. If you do not configure compression inside the application, IIS will handle it automatically. But whether it is IIS compression or application compression, the ultimate goal is to save bandwidth and improve response speed.

[HTTP Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/)

[Why use IIS Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/iis-compression/iis-compression-overview#why-use-iis-compression)